# How to store the user input session and retrieve it again?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm facing a problem with my note taking app wherein the input of the user gets saved in a list through a card form but I have no idea how to click that card and retrieve the same session of what the user inputted so that I can edit it and replace the previous value completely. I was thinking of maybe having a separate key-value pair for the list so I can separate the content and the title but I didn't know how to call it, since currently it is `data[index]`.

My idea is to basically save the note then be able to click it, edit and save it again without creating a new note.

Video Sample:

[Flutter notes issue](https://youtu.be/XGKGzqSX2Wg)

I have tried to use `initState` and `didChangeDependencies` but it didn't really work out well.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

final data = [];
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Home(),
    ));

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
          'Glass',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
            letterSpacing: 1.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 12.0, bottom: 10, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  dense: true,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SharedPreference1()));
                  },
                  title: Text(
                    data[index],
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 9.0,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          await Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SharedPreference1()));
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[300],
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    ));
  }
}

Future<bool> saveData(String nameKey, String value) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return await preferences.setString(nameKey, value);
}

Future<String> loadData(String nameKey) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return preferences.getString(nameKey);
}

class Hero extends State<SharedPreference1> {
  TextEditingController _notesController1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _notesController2 = new TextEditingController();
  Widget buildSaveButton(context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 340.0),
      child: RaisedButton.icon(
        elevation: 9.0,
        icon: Icon(Icons.save),
        label: Text('Save'),
        color: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () async {
          await saveData("_key_name", _notesController1.text);
          await setData();
          print(data);
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                buildHeading(context),
                buildNotesText(),
                buildSaveButton(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildHeading(context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, top: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                maxLines: 1,
                controller: _notesController1,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Note Title',
                ),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.close, color: Colors.white, size: 27),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildNotesText() {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: TextField(
          maxLines: null,
          controller: _notesController2,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Create Note Here',
          ),
          cursorColor: Colors.white,
          autofocus: true,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  setData() {
    loadData("_key_name").then((value) {
      setState(() {
        if (value == null) {
          print("Value not available.");
        } else {
          data.add(value);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

class SharedPreference1 extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreference1() : super();
  @override
  Hero createState() => Hero();
}
```

Comment: You can use shared preferences to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this.

1. Create a Note class.

```
class Note {
  int id;
  String title;
  String content;
}
```

2. Change your `SharedPreference1`

```
class SharedPreference1 extends StatefulWidget {

  final Note note;

  SharedPreference1({this.note}) : super();
  @override
  Hero createState() => Hero();
}
```

3. Pass the Note object to `SharedPreference1` when you are editing the note.

```
Note newNote = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => SharedPreference1(note: data[index],)));
setsState((){
  data[index] = newNote;
});
```

Wait until the next screen is popped and set the returned object into the list.

4.When user save the note check if your is editing the note of creating a new one.

```
if(widget.note == null){
  //New Note
  //save the note

}else{
  //Editing the note
  //save the note
  //return the note to home screen 
  Note newNote = Note();
  newNote.id = widget.note.id;
  newNote.title = //set title;
  newNote.content = //set content
  //return this newNote to previous screen
  Navigator.of(context).pop(newNote);
}
```

5. When you add a new note do as you were doing before.

Here your `data` list will be list of `Note`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I just tried the code and added it onto mine. The problem now is that the value doesn't get saved in the list anymore, idk if I am missing something else or no. Anyways, here is the link for the code with all your changes, https://hastebin.com/zejutuwere.java

Comment: Okay that link expired. Just check this link. https://pastebin.com/Jis2D3ms